# How to get the parameter from Servlet to Html page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I am try to save a Text as Attribute in servlet and forward it to a HTML page.Then need to show it in Html page body. 
    Help me to send the data as response to HTML.then help to show the value in HTML page.
    In JSP is working fine.but i need to send the response to html page and show it.

```
Here i am using Request dispatcher for send the request and response to html page.
but i am not clear with how to display it in html.Help me tp solve. 

 thanks

 //NewServlet.java

 public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setAttribute("Cricket", "Sachin");
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
   }
 }
```

//index.html

[image]

Comment: `index.html` is not jsp

Comment: when you have jsp use JSTL

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to preprocess the html, and replace "TODO write content" with whatever it is you want to show.

Comment: But it would be much easier with a JSP

Comment: Why aren't you using a JSP instead?

Comment: @MauricePerry i need this only html.so please help me to solve.

Comment: @ScaryWombat please tell the posibilties to do this in html

Comment: why do you **need** html?

Comment: Is index.html a file in your webapp?

Comment: @MauricePerry yes dude

Comment: in sample program i have it in my web app.but future it is hosted in naother server

Comment: And what control do you have on the content of the index.html?

Comment: If the file is on another server, the approach is completely different

Answer (score -1):

If the file index.html is on another server, you don't need to use the request's attributes because you need to do another request, and the servlet API doesn't provide what you need.

You can obtain the file's content by using a HttpURLConnection for instance. Then you need to process that content to insert your data, then write the result to the servet response.